# regarding Integer solutions

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)=x^7-105x+12.$ Show that $f(m)$ is not prime for any integer $m$.

Comment: Can you factor the polynomial?

Comment: Member for 2 years and 11 months and You don't write about Your own attempts? Did You read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)?

Comment: @user247327 The polynomial $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, so there is no non-trivial factorisation.

Comment: @user 247327 which test you're using to conclude that f(x) is irreducible over $Q$

Comment: @Ravi Eisenstein with $p=3$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde $f$ is irreducible over $Q$. From this how can we conclude that $f(m)$ is not prime for any integer $m$.

Comment: @Ravi We cannot conclude this. Take $f=x^2+x+1$. It is irreducible, but $f(1)$ is prime.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I had the same doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $2\mid f(x)$ for all integers $x$. On the other hand, $f(x)=2$ is impossible over the integers, since $x^7-105x+10$ has no rational root by the rational root theorem.